# Django count related objects

Tags: python, django

How can I count related objects in Django (in less than *N* queries, where *N* is number of object).

To clarify, let's say I have tables *A* and *B*. Every *B* is connected to exactly one *A*. Approach I tried:

```
A.objects.select_related().filter(attr=val)
A[i].B_set.count()
```

Of course, for every *A[i]* I want to find out number of *B* objects Django executes one query.

So the question is - is there a way to optimize that?

Comment: What do you mean by "Every B is connected to exactly one A."? Does B has a foreign key field point to A? Or B has a OneToOne field pointing A?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have not tried how many queries are executed, but the Django way should be using [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/). For example:

```
from django.db.models import Count

q = A.objects.select_related('B').annotate(num_B=Count('B'))
print A[0].num_B
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but I get the error saying the global name 'Count' is not defined when doing this.

Comment: nvm, found the answer: from django.db.models import Count

Answer (score 6):

Since Django 2.0 `Count()` aggregate function [accepts `filter` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count), which allows applying additional restrictions on the related objects queryset.
Works like this:

```
A.objects.select_related().annotate(
    total=models.Count('myrelated__pk', filter=Q(only_items='that-i-need'))
).all()
```

Answer (score 5):

I have to answer my own question :) If object of A is queried something like this:

```
A.objects.select_related().filter(atrr=val).annotate(n_b=models.Count('B'))
```

This creates very long query, but at least there is just one.