# Count number of foreign keys in Django

Tags: python, django

I've read the documentation and all the other answers on here but I can't seem to get my head around it.

**I need to count the number of foreign keys in an other table connected by a foreign key to a row from a queryset.**

```
class PartReference(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    code = models.IntegerField()

class Part(models.Model):
    code = models.ForeignKey(PartReference)
    serial_number = models.IntegerField()
```

I'll do something like:

```
results = PartReference.objects.all()
```

But I want a variable containing the count of the number of parts like any other field, something like:

```
results[0].count
```

to ultimately do something like:

```
print(results[0].name, results[0].code, results[0].count)
```

I can't wrap my head around the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/)- There is a some stuff going on with `entry_set` in the example, but doesn't explain where `entry` came from or how it was defined.

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... what are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @Sayse I put it in bold at the top and tried to clarify it: I need to count the number of foreign keys in an other table connected by a foreign key to a row from a queryset.

Comment: The `_set` thing is explained *in the first section* of the page you link to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_set` is used by django to look up reverse queries on database relationships and is appended to the end of a foreign key field name to state that you want to query all objects related so in your case that would be `part_set`, which means for any given result you can access the count of that part set as follows:

```
results = PartReference.objects.all()
for result in results:    
    print(result.name, result.code, results.part_set.count())
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't wrap my head around the Django documentation- There is a some
>   stuff going on with entry_set in the example, but doesn't explain
>   where entry came from or how it was defined.

`entry_set` comes from the `Entry` table, that's weird I have to say that Django doc doesn't explain that, it's kind of implicit, e.g. if B is linked to A, then it will be `b_set` to access B from A.

Coming back to your problem, I think this was asked many times here, e.g. [Django count related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569975/django-count-related-objects)