# How to count products in category django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I need to show how many items in each category, like Ihave 3 items in category Phones and I want to do this **Phones(3)**.
I tried to to some methods in models,but it doesn't work.

```py
def count_products(self):
      return Category.objects.all().count()
```

also tried in **views.py:**

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['grade_info'] = self.get_ordered_grade_info()
    context['category'] = Category.objects.count()
    return context
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django count related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569975/django-count-related-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `annotate` function to do aggrigation of calculations on the data at the database level, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Count
catigouris = Category.objects.annotate(
items_count=Count('related_name_to_items')
)
```

The ORM query above will return an extra attribute called `items_count` grouped by category.

Comment: i need to put this into models.py or views.py?

Comment: You can't put it into models.py because it's responsible for tables and attributes only, So you have to put it into views.py (your endpoint function or class).